# Query did not conform to the expectations getting youtube analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, google-api, google-oauth

I have created a rails application using omniauth to let users login with google and track their youtube video analytics. I use the following gems: [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2), [google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) and followed some of the [provided examples](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples). The users authorize the application to get the analytics (once) and later they are collected on a daily basis.

This is omniauth.rb scope, client_id and client_secret. I do succeed to obtain access_token and refresh_token.

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], { 
  :scope => "yt-analytics.readonly,userinfo.email,userinfo.profile" 
}
```

Successfully obtaining the client access token in background with the private key:

```
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('xxx-privatekey.p12', 'notasecret')
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
  :issuer => 'xxx-yyy@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
  :signing_key => key)
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

I'm executing the report query with the following line:

```
# [Query 1]

client.execute!(:api_method => youtube_analytics.reports.query, :parameters => {
  :ids => 'channel==own_channel_id', 
  'end-date' => '2014-02-15', 
  'start-date' => '2014-02-01', 
  :metrics => 'views'
})
```

Even for this general query i receive the following error message:

```
Google::APIClient::ClientError: Invalid query. Query did not conform to the expectations.
```

I do succeed to obtain the correct json if i execute the url version of [Query 1] and even of a more complex query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUown_channel_id&start-date=2013-10-01&end-date=2014-10-31&metrics=views%2Ccomments%2CfavoritesAdded%2Clikes%2Cdislikes%2CestimatedMinutesWatched%2CaverageViewDuration&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Could you please advise?

Thank you.

**Update 1:** After further investigation i believe the issue might be with the generation of the token, because this is the only difference in the requests (mine and the one generated by the google api explorer).

Probably not the main problem, but still: the bearer token generated by `client.authorization.fetch_access_token!` is 78 characters long and the token by the google api explorer is 85 characters long. To verify that, before `client.execute!` i added `client.authorization.access_token = [token-obtained-by-api-explorer]` and that returned the correct results.

I'm adding two full examples (both return "... Query did not conform to the expectations..." error): https://gist.github.com/rebelact/9135573 and https://gist.github.com/rebelact/9135594 . I got my channel id from https://www.youtube.com/account_advanced

**Update 2:** After more digging it turns out I had to refresh the token with the refresh_token once i have it. I found this comment - https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/37#issuecomment-15734250, which initially refreshed the token. But after some point it started to throw the error `"{'error' : 'invalid_grant'}"`. I read about it and i believe i pass the right credentials and my clock is synced according to NTP (i got the same error on heroku). Could you please advise? (let me know if you want to open another question)

Comment: Ruby client may not be setting fields correctly. We'll look into this.

Comment: @IbrahimUlukaya I updated the answer with the progress so far